# Contact name suddenly missing

Tags: iphone, contacts, exchange

I recently deleted my Exchange email account (old work email) and now some of my contacts are "missing". When I search for them to send a text message they are there but their names disappear. They are not, however, in my contacts list. Anyone know how to fix?  I've done a reboot but it didn't help.

Comment: Were these contacts stored in the Exchange mailbox you deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Not much you can do if they were exchange contacts. The messages will still be there because they were created before you removed the account that stored all your contacts. You could probably re-add the exchange account, and see if you can mass-move the contacts to your iCloud group in contacts - probably best to try this on a mac if you have one.

Comment: How can I get my contacts out of the cloud? I should know how but I don't!

Answer (score 0):

Add that exchange account back, you saved those contacts to it.

Comment: I tried but I don't have access to it anymore